# TableView Public To all Users

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a chat room app. Currently, when users signs in they are given their own table view to upload data too.

Instead of each user having their own **personal table view** I would like all users to be connected to **one (public) table view** so everyone can see what's posted. Hence a chat room app.

- These are 3 separate logins and what it looks like for each user when they post a message:

[image: 3 Seperate users when logging in and posting to the Tableview]

- This is what I want. To have each tableview cell represent a different message from a different user. All publicly viewed on one tableview. Not on separate table views:

[image: What I want the tableView to do when a user posts]

How can I make the table view public? When I log in as a different user I would like the previous message to still be there from each user. Hence a chat room.

[image]

```
{
   "rules": {
  "Users":{
     ".read": "true",
     ".write": "true"
},
  "general_room" : {
    ".read": "true",
     ".write": "true"
  }
    }
}
```

**GeneralChatroom.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

struct postStruct {
    let username : String!
    let message : String!
    let photoURL : String!
}

class GeneralChatroom: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextField: UITextField!

    var generalRoomDataArr = [postStruct]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140


        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid            
        ref.child("general_room").child("chat").child(userID!).queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {snapshot in

            let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let username = snapDict?["Username"] as? String ?? ""
            let message = snapDict?["Message"] as? String ?? ""
            let firebaseUserPhotoURL = snapDict?["photo_url"] as? String ?? ""

            self.generalRoomDataArr.insert(postStruct(username: username, message: message, photoURL: firebaseUserPhotoURL), at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })

    }

    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "BackToRoom", sender: nil)
    }    

    //Message Send button is pressed data uploaded to firebase
    @IBAction func sendButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let message : String = self.messageTextField.text!

        UploadGeneralChatRoom(message: message) //upload to general_room

        self.messageTextField.text = nil
        messageTextField.resignFirstResponder()//Quit keyboard
        self.tableView.reloadData() //Reload tableView
        //UploadUserData() //Update Rank in database
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return generalRoomDataArr.count // your number of cell here
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        let usernameLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        usernameLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].username

        let messageLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        messageLabel.numberOfLines=0 // line wrap
        messageLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        messageLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].message


        //initialize UI Profile Image
        let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UIImageView

        //Make Porfile Image Cirlce
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        //User Profile image in tableview
        if generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].photoURL != nil
        {
            //let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UIImageView

            if let url = NSURL(string: generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].photoURL) {

                if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {

                    imageView.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
                }
            }
        }

        // your cell coding
        return cell!
    }       

}//END CLASS
```

**Upload to firebase**

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

func UploadGeneralChatRoom(message : String) {

    //Firebase Initialization
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    //var storage: FIRStorageReference!
    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    //storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference()


    //Get Data from database resend to database
    ref.child("Users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

        let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let username = snapDict?["Username"] as? String ?? ""
        let firebaseUserPhotoURL = snapDict?["photo_url"] as? String ?? ""           
        ref.child("general_room").child("chat").child(userID!).childByAutoId().setValue(["Username": username, "uid": userID!, "Message" : message, "photo_url" : firebaseUserPhotoURL])

    })        
}
```

Comment: show us your firebase structure

Comment: in case you are storing chatrooms in particular user child. You need to create a public child and store all chatrooms there. This way all users can access those chatrooms.

Comment: You may be over complicating this task: You need a node called general_chat, and when a user posts a message to general_chat, it's stored in that node as a child. All users observe the general_chat node and thusly are notified when a new message is added. In turn when each client receives that notification event, the message is added to that clients tableView. This keeps all clients synch'd so they are all seeing new messages they are posted. Any time a new user logs in, they will observe the general_chat node and see all of the prior posts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulator and iOS device tableView Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569502/simulator-and-ios-device-tableview-firebase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your firebase database is setup but you are posting to `child("Users").child(userID!)`
but reading from 
`child("general_room").child("chat").child(userID!)`

You would need to read and write to the same location.

Also:
try to safely unwrap your optional values:

```
if let userId = userID {
    ref.child("Users").child(userId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

            let snapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let username = snapDict?["Username"] as? String ?? ""
            let firebaseUserPhotoURL = snapDict?["photo_url"] as? String ?? ""

            ref.child("general_room").child("chat").child(userID!).childByAutoId().setValue(["Username": username, "uid": userID!, "Message" : message, "photo_url" : firebaseUserPhotoURL])
     })
}
```

Comment: Where you are getting your data in your viewcontroller you add .child(UserID!) after .child(chat). So when retrieving these messages you need to have either the id from all users in the chat or setup a chat with an id so all user can access that chatroom.

Comment: Bob De Kort and @jay i kind of get what your saying but can you go into more detail. Or show me how to set it up so i get a better understanding.

Comment: @rv7284 can you explain in greater detail.

Comment: Ok:
So under your chat section in your firebase database you have groups of messages under id's (eg.: hvl6stvu...) these are (as far as I know) your user id's. You post to here using your user id that is logged in.
So when retrieving with a user id that is logged in you only get access to that users messages.

Comment: Instead of this:
`ref.child("general_room").child("chat").child(userID!).childByAutoId().setValue(["Username": username, "uid": userID!, "Message" : message, "photo_url" : firebaseUserPhotoURL])`
remove .child(UserID!)
`ref.child("general_room").child("chat").childByAutoId().setValue(["Username": username, "uid": userID!, "Message" : message, "photo_url" : firebaseUserPhotoURL])`